# Finding the fixed point of $\exp(-x^2)$ numerically

Tags: numerical-methods

> Consider the function $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$. With a starting approximation of $p_0=0$,  use the iteration scheme $p_n=e^{-p_{n-1}^2}$ to approximate the fixed point on $[0,1]$ to within $5 \times 10^{-7}$.

So, our teacher did not go over this section, but assigned it for homework and I have no idea where to even start with this. Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: You need to calculate (see Michael's answer below) untill $n=84$ untill you get the answer to desired accuracy so don't do it by hand:)

Comment: Why go until n=84?

Comment: You will have to keep iterating until $|p_n - p_{n-1}| < 5\cdot 10^{-7}$. It just turns out numerically that you will have to go until $n \sim 80$ before this accuracy is achieved.

Answer (score 3):

It seems self-explanatory.  If it doesn't strike you that way, let's try this:

You wrote $p_n=e^{-p_{n-1}^2}$.

The index $n$ can be $0,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$.

You said $p_0=0$.

So we have
\begin{align}
p_1 & = e^{-p_0^2} & (\text{In this case, $n=1$ and so $n-1=0$.}) \\[8pt]
p_2 & = e^{-p_1^2} & (\text{In this case, $n=2$ and so $n-1=1$.}) \\[8pt]
p_3 & = e^{-p_2^2} & (\text{In this case, $n=3$ and so $n-1=2$.}) \\[8pt]
& \text{and so on.}
\end{align}
You know $p_0$.  In the first line above, you find $p_1$.  It's a number.  You use it in the second line, and thus you find $p_2$.  That's another number.  Then you use that in the third line to find $p_3$.  And so on.

---

You might also note that $p_{2n}<p_{2n+2}<p_{2n-1}<p_{2n+1}$. In words, the terms jump back and forth over the solution.  As a result, your error after $n$ iterates is less than $|p_n-p_{n+1}|$.  This allows you to determine when to stop or (actually, I presume) when your program should stop.

Comment: I hope you find my edit to be satisfactory.

Comment: Yes, thank you Mark.